# Android - Use two mics at the same time

Tags: android, audio, external, microphone

For a schoolproject I'm working on an android app (with AndroidStudio) that will require to read two mics at the same time. I only need to read the decibels and do not need clear speech or anything.

I'm looking to use the onboard mic and an external mic that is plugged into the audio jack. Is there a way to use both mics at the same time and read both inputs simultaneously?

Comment: not sure, but I don't think Android SDK has such abbility

Comment: The existence of [`AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_STEREO`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioFormat#CHANNEL_IN_STEREO) suggests some devices can read from a stereo microphone. That means you could use the R channel as one mic, and the L channel as another.